# fusion-tables auto populate fields in new record

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'm using fusion tables to store a client database. I have ~300 records of clients and their installations, but I need to add records for repairs. I need an easy way of creating a "repair" ticket, where most of the information from the specific client record is visible without having to copy the info manually for each additional repair. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use case I would create another table containing the repairs, which contains some kind of key column to identify the client. This could be the name of the client or simply a number (id).

When you have your new repair table and the existing client table, you can simply [create a so called merge table](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171254). This new table contains the information of repairs and client. If you add or change data in one of the tables, the merge table automatically contains this data.

Technically, a merge table is a [left outer join (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join).

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked beautifully! Tell me, is there an easy way to add a drop down to a field? Not type the name of our tech but choose from a dropdown menu?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You could try to manage your data with Google Spreadsheet (where it is quite easy to add a drop-down), and then upload the data to Fusion Tables. There is even a [discussion about syncing spreadsheets with Fusion Tables](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/groups/fusionTablesApiGroup?place=topic%2Ffusion-tables-users-group%2FaIgKy__7r7w%2Fdiscussion).

Comment: Thanks! That's not going to work for me. Are you familiar with any way to sync up fusion data with google calendar though? I have a column designated for appointment date. If that could feed the client name into the appointment slot on a calendar it would be amazing.